# Avoid jQuery Plugin re-implementation of methods/definitions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently struggeling with jQuery Plugins. Here, I am using the ["Tag-Handler" plugin](http://ioncache.github.io/Tag-Handler/) to implement tag handling for the website.

Initialization of plugin is something like this:

```
        $('#plugin-optsel-colormixed').tagHandler({
            assignedTags: stored_tags.length ? stored_tags.split(",") : [],
            inputField: ...,
            onAdd: function() {
                ...
            },
            afterAdd: function() {
                ...
            },
            afterDelete: function() {
                ...
            }
        });
```

So this is quite straight-forward.

Now, my plan was to add some tags to the taghandler afterwards. I thought, this could be easily done by writing additional code block like this:

```
$('#plugin-optsel-colormixed').tagHandler({
    assignedTags: [...]
}
```

However, this will override the previous definitions of onAdd, afterAdd and afterDelete, so that this function won't work anymore after assigning tags as above.

Is there a way to avoid that? How can I re-write the plugin, so that previous defined methods and definitions can be re-used?

Comment: Use $.extend(), learn more about it [HERE](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)

Comment: I would not recommend that plugin. It's old, has no evidence of being actively maintained, and doesn't do anything like the perfectly reasonable stuff you're looking for. It won't even work at all in Internet Explorer due to its use of `const`.  Good plugins generally support an "options" command (and other similar things) to let you update existing configurations.

Comment: @Pointy: Which `const` are you mentioning? Sure, tag-it is old, but is still based on jQuery. Can you recommend some similar plugins?

Comment: @Robiston right at the top of tagit.js. I don't know of anything similar.

Comment: @SunnyRGupta: Do you know how to use `$.extend()`, when having objects like `$('#plugin-optsel-colormixed')?`

Comment: Old options should exist somewhere. You can simply add onto them and reinitialize the plugin. Better than having to recreate the entire options panel again.